# Entity Framwork Database First Propertyname problem with 2 Foreign Keys

Tags: entity-framework

I have a problem with Entity Framework.
If I add a Datatable from my DB over my Entity Data Model and this model has 2 Foreign Keys to the same table, the names of this Foreign Keys becomes confusing. Can I make any configurations to set this Foreign Key names beforehand?
I dont want to make any changes after the model is generated.

Here a example from my model

```
public partial class PERSON
{
   public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
   public string NAME { get; set; }
   public System.Guid TABLE_REGION_FK { get; set; }
        
   public virtual TABLE_REGION TABLE_REGION { get; set; } // -> property name should be TABLE_REGION_PARENT
   public virtual TABLE_REGION TABLE_REGION1 { get; set; } // -> property name should be TABLE_REGION_CHIELD
}
```

Comment: You can do this with EF Core Power Tools

Comment: I am working in dot.net 4.8 :-(